# How to add states on the Bloch sphere from a master equation?

Tags: programming, bloch-sphere, qutip

Can you please help me to find an answer to this question: I am using qutip for the study of quantum systems. suppose I have calculated the solution of the master equation using the `mcsolve` function and let it be

```
output = mcsolve(H,psi0,tlist,c_op_list,exp_op_list,ntraj)
```

If I want to plot the expectation value points on the Bloch sphere, I can use

```
b.add_points(output.expect[0], output.expect[1], output.expect[2])
```

But how can I add the states on the Bloch sphere? I am sorry if there is anything wrong in the way I have asked the question because I am new to the programming.